# What are currently the best free options to use CUDA on F#

Tags: cuda, f#, gpu

I want to use CUDA in F#. While Alea.CuBase seems really great it is unfortunately not free. What are the best options for using CUDA in F#? Are there any other free libraries which are actively being developed? Are they much worse than CUDA on C in terms of performance **EDIT** and features (especially I want to use texture memory for my application)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FSCL](https://github.com/GabrieleCocco/FSCL.Compiler) is the most complete tool I know of. It targets OpenCL (not CUDA), but now that OpenCL is maturing (especially once the OpenCL 2.0 standard is finalized) that's probably the best option for many uses; if you specifically need to use CUDA (e.g., to use some CUDA library that doesn't work with OpenCL), you may be able to modify the FSCL compiler so it targets CUDA instead.

Don Syme wrote about FSCL on his blog earlier this year: [FSCL - Compiling F# to OpenCL for High-Performance over Multi-core and Many-core devices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2013/06/30/fscl-compiling-f-to-opencl-for-high-performance-over-multi-core-and-many-core-devices.aspx)

Comment: With version 3 [Alea GPU](http://www.aleagpu.com) is also free. It targets CUDA and is very complete. It is a true compiler and not a source code generator which relies on a third party OpenCL C or CUDA C compiler such as all the other tools. As such it also supports debugging of GPU code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to launch CUDA-kernels written in plain CUDA-C and compiled by nvcc in an F# application, I recommend you [managedCuda](http://managedcuda.codeplex.com), which gives access to all available CUDA features (I maintain this library).

If you want to do code conversion, meaning writing your kernels in F# being converted to a CUDA-kernel, then you might want to have a look at [cudafy](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/); with the drawback of missing features like e.g. texture memory.

Both are available under LGPL license and are actively maintained.